# If/While loop with EarlGrey from Swift

Tags: swift3, earlgrey

Iam a beginner in EarlGrey. Before i used them, I used swift. Now, is my problem I have a while loop, I don't know how I can make a while loop in EarlGrey.

I want this while loop written in EarlGrey :

```
if XCUIApplication().otherElements[XYZ].exists { while !XCUIApplication().buttons[Button].exists { 
XCUIApplication().otherElements[XYZ].swipeLeft() } 
XCTAssertTrue(XCUIApplication().buttons[Button].exists, "Button not exist!") XCUIApplication().buttons[Button].tap() 
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you basically wish to just swipe left as long as two buttons are visible?

Comment: Yes, and i want to check with the asserttrue if the button exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

> if existAccessibilityID(AccessibilityIdentifier: "XYZ") {
>                EarlGrey.select(elementWithMatcher: grey_accessibilityID(Button)).usingSearch(grey_swipeFastInDirection(GREYDirection.left), onElementWith: grey_accessibilityID(PageViewController)).perform(grey_tap())
>           }

Ok, I have found a solution...